# Flutter - How to start a listview directly from bottom without animations?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter chat app, and once the user enters the chat, i want it to start from the bottom(most recent chats), but i can't seem to find a solution without any transitions/animations which looks so bad once the page loads. 

Here is what i am using right now:

```
var _listController = ScrollController();
override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _listController.animateTo(_listController.position.maxScrollExtent,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: Curves.easeIn);
    });
    super.initState();
}

ListView.builder(
              controller: _listController,
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: Provider.of<Chat>(context).chatSize,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return something
```

I also tried:

```
      _listController.jumpTo(_listController.position.maxScrollExtent);
```

with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `reverse: true` property for a bottom-to-up list.